# Curve_fit resulting in a flat line

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I'm new to the Scipy.optimize *curve_fit()* tool. I'm trying to find a function that best models the curve in the figure (part of a time series signal), but meanwhile I was just fitting a sine curve to it and got a flat line. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the figure and the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
xdata = np.arange(0, len(ydata), 1)   
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)

def func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.sin(b * x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[100,70])
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'g')
plt.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Given the shape of your curve, shouldn't you use `p0=[-100,70]`?

Comment: Doesn't look like an actual flat line, it's just a sine wave with a very small amplitude. Have you tried printing the values returned? I'm guessing `a` is tiny.

Comment: Just tried it @berkelem, the result was the same.

Comment: @MarkRansom `popt` returns `array([ -0.32126543,  70.00625782])`

Comment: That might be a local minimum of the least-squares objective function.  That type of result is not unusual when fitting a sinusoidal function.  Try different values for `p0`, and take a look at @JamesPhillips answer for another approach that can work well.

Comment: Your plot shows roughly one cycle over a range of about 150.  So a rough guess of the angular frequency `b` is 2*pi/150.  Try `p0 = [-100, 0.04]`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser for `p0=[500,100]` I can see something, but still very small and no fit whatsoever. Which other function do you suggest instead of `np.sin`?

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: You're right @WarrenWeckesser, for `p0=[-100, 0.04]` `popt` returns `array([ -1.00433872e+02,   4.90491028e-02])` and I see a sinusoidal cycle with an amplitude similar to the signal. But still away from the best fit (I guess).

Comment: Your data is only very roughly a sine function, so you won't get much better than that with your current model.  You could do a little better by also including a phase parameter: def `func(x, a, b, c): return a * np.sin(b * x + c)`.  Whether or not that is worth it (and whether or not you should explore other models) depends on what you are going to do with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution genetic algorithm for initial parameter estimation. My example data has an offset, so I added that to the equation. The scipy implementation of Differential Evolution uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space which requires bounds within which to search, in this example those bounds are taken from the data maximum and minimum values.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

xData = numpy.array([19.1647, 18.0189, 16.9550, 15.7683, 14.7044, 13.6269, 12.6040, 11.4309, 10.2987, 9.23465, 8.18440, 7.89789, 7.62498, 7.36571, 7.01106, 6.71094, 6.46548, 6.27436, 6.16543, 6.05569, 5.91904, 5.78247, 5.53661, 4.85425, 4.29468, 3.74888, 3.16206, 2.58882, 1.93371, 1.52426, 1.14211, 0.719035, 0.377708, 0.0226971, -0.223181, -0.537231, -0.878491, -1.27484, -1.45266, -1.57583, -1.61717])
yData = numpy.array([0.644557, 0.641059, 0.637555, 0.634059, 0.634135, 0.631825, 0.631899, 0.627209, 0.622516, 0.617818, 0.616103, 0.613736, 0.610175, 0.606613, 0.605445, 0.603676, 0.604887, 0.600127, 0.604909, 0.588207, 0.581056, 0.576292, 0.566761, 0.555472, 0.545367, 0.538842, 0.529336, 0.518635, 0.506747, 0.499018, 0.491885, 0.484754, 0.475230, 0.464514, 0.454387, 0.444861, 0.437128, 0.415076, 0.401363, 0.390034, 0.378698])


def func(x, a, b, offset):
    return a * numpy.sin(b * x) + offset

# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: very interesting method, but I guess this might be overkill for my simple problem. Do you know any function that resembles to my signal?

Comment: Possibly a sine wave plus a straight line, something like "a * np.sin(b * x) + c*x + d". I notice that what appear to be the sine wave maximum and minimum points are not at the same levels.